# How to change an Android application to paid after setting the Google Merchant account?

Tags: android, google-play

We had the Android application free. There was the link for setting the Google merchant account near the Pricing tag on the development console.   We successfully set the Google Merchant Account and the link disappeared.
However, we still do not see any Pricing option besides Free on the development console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. There's a warning about this when you first publish the application. Once you set it to free, it's free forever. If you really need to do this, you need to unpublish this free version and publish a "new app" as the paid version (you'll have to change the package name too).

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  See details [here](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/support/bin/answer.py?answer=138412)

Answer (score 2):

A free Market app must remain free.  You'd have to make a second listing for the app (with a different package name) to charge for it.

Answer (score 0):

> "Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price."

Original post  [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?visit_id=1-636558273519012181-3217689816&rd=1#paid_free)