# Changing from free app to paid app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

This question might be off topic, but I wanted to ask the fellow developers.

Is there a way on Google play I could change my free app to a paid app?

What would happen to the existing users if it is allowed? Would they be asked to pay when the new update is available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an Android application to paid after setting the Google Merchant account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232772/how-to-change-an-android-application-to-paid-after-setting-the-google-merchant-a)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make paid Android app free for a week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618015/make-paid-android-app-free-for-a-week)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could add in-app payment processing to your free app and charge for enhanced features.  Per

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1153479

"By using the in-app billing feature you can add revenue-generating features to your applications, enhancing the revenue potential of paid applications and turning free applications into new revenue sources."

Now, could you disable functionality that was already available in the free app, and then charge via in-app payments to have it restored?  Technically I do think it could be done, since you are in control of your implementation of those features, although you would have to investigate whether that would be a violation of Google's policies.

However, doing it might alienate your users, and if word got around they might even stop updating your app to avoid the "trap."  So a much better approach would probably be to add enticing *new* functionality that enhances the existing functionality, and then charge for *it*.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot change a free app to a paid app on the Google Play store. You could re-upload under a different name, but this would obviously fracture your user base.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Check [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?visit_id=1-636558273519012181-3217689816&rd=1#paid_free)

> "Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price."

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Its not possible, we need create paid app always then you can make it free