# Change the price of Android application?

Tags: android

I'm planning to upload my Android application on Google Play soon.
And I heard that change the Charge-mode to Free-mode is able to do, but the reverse is impossible due to Google's policy.

And I'm wondering two things.

**1. Then is it possible to change it from Charge-mode to Free-mode for a limited time(maybe 1-week or something), and then change it back to Charge mode, is this possible???**

**2. Is it possible to discount my application's price from $2(US) to $1(US) for a limited time as well???**

Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

1. No;
2. Yes.

You can change price at any moment, but not to 0$.

Comment: Thank you Fenix, but i heard that changing the Charge mode to Free mode is possible.... but why you said "You can change price at any moment, but not to 0$." ??

Comment: I mean there is no such option like "change to 0$". I've read also (but never used, though) it is possible to change app status to free, but it's more like changing the state of the app (which can be done once), not the price only (which can be done many times, as long as app is paid).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make the application payable if you set the app as free of change. But Viceversa it works. You can change the price of app any time you want (even free). Remember if you change the price to zero you can't change the price.
The lower value of payable app is $1.

Detailed here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en&ref_topic=15867

So if you wanna get some payable/free periods there some solutions how to do:

1. Use 2 version of application (free of chaged and payable). So there must be 2 different packages on Google Play. Imho the best way to protect your data.
2. Or use the subsribtions (in-app purchase)
   More detailed information (subsriptions): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en&ref_topic=15867
3. Or create payable applications which have content and give it to main app via broadcast reciever.

Answer (score 0):

according to android privacy & policy changing your application to free application from paid may be impossible.may be this is not a good solution but how about implementing in-app purchase to your application?
may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838735/726547) answer will help.

[in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)