# How to upload same app twice on play console?

Tags: android, upload, console, playback

I uploaded an app on google play but made it accidentally free. Now i want to upload the same app again and make it paid. How do i make that? When I try to upload the apk again, it says:

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in app signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it.

How do I sign a new key (please explain this to a newbie, im not a programmer, I created an apk file with thinkable)

Comment: You will have to change package name of your paid app.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115614/changing-from-free-app-to-paid-app-on-google-play

Comment: How to change package name of the app?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to be aware of:

- First, no two apps in the store can have the same package name (i.e. unique identifier). In Thunkable, the package name is `com.{username}.{appname}`, so you will need to change either the username of the app name before uploading your new app.
- Then, there is the question of the keystore (See "Keystores" section in [Thunkable docs](https://docs.thunkable.com/thunkable-classic-android/publish#6--keystores)). It seems that you opted out of "Play Signing" for the first app you created, and now you opted in for your second app, but used the same cryptographic key for both apps. This can lead to security issues when you use the same key for two different purposes (simplifying a bit, sorry). Thunkable unfortunately does not seem to support generating new keystores, so you have two options: 1) Create a new account with Thunkable (which should generate a new keystore), or 2) Opt out of "App Signing by Play" when you're prompted in the Play Console when you upload your app.

Hope that helps! Good luck :)